# PowerShell - trouble with referencing user object last login information

Tags: loops, powershell, windows-7

In my environment, the Domain Users group is a member of the local Administrators group on each machine and I need to remove this but I need to make sure the recently active users stay as members of the local Administrators group.  The path I've chosen to take is to add any user who has logged into the machine in the last 30 days, add them to the Local Administrators group directly and then remove Domain Users from the Local Administrators group.

I query the lastaccesstime of all of the folders in c:\users\ and then take whatever folder name is recent enough and manually add it to the local administrator group, and then remove the Domain Users group from the local Administrators.

```
foreach ($file in gci c:\users) {
  if ((($file).lastaccesstime) -gt ((get-date).AddDays(-30))) {
    write-host $file.name “has been added to local Administrators group”
    net localgroup administrators $file.name /add
  }
  else {
    write-host $file.name “hasn’t been touched in over 30 days”
  }
}
net localgroup administrators “domain users” /delete
```

This seems pretty straight forward and works on most of the machines I am testing with but occasionally I find some user folders don't report that they were modified recently even when someone has logged onto that machine.  That being said - I was advised to test the ntuser.dat file in each users home folder instead but I can't seem to make that work.

I was hoping there was something like an object I could query for the last logged on users, or some way to reference user objects that have logged on previously in the past and query their lastlogon, or lastmodified date or something like that.

Can anyone provide some guidance here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use grab all [`Win32_UserProfile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee886409(v=vs.85).aspx) instances belonging to domain users and inspect the `LastUseTime` property instead:

```
$Threshold = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)

# Non-builtin regular user SIDs are always prefixed S-1-5-21-
$DomainUserFilter = "SID LIKE 'S-1-5-21-%'"

# Retrieve user profiles
$DomainProfiles = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile -Filter $DomainUserFilter

foreach($UserProfile in $DomainProfiles)
{
  # Check if profile was ever used, skip if not
  if(-not $UserProfile.LastUseTime)
  {
    continue
  }

  # Convert the datetime string to a proper datetime object
  $LastUsed = $UserProfile.ConvertToDateTime($UserProfile.LastUseTime)

  # Compare against threshold
  if($LastUsed -gt $Threshold)
  {
    # Resolve user profile SID to account name
    $Account = (New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier $UserProfile.SID).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
    if($?)
    {
      # Add to Administrators group
      net localgroup administrators $Account.Value /add
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mathias, I like the look of this as it was definitely get-wmiobject that I was looking for - in another thread I got a reply to use a modified version of that.  However when I try to run this I get the following error (4 times)

`Cannot index into a null array.
At line:14 char:5
+     $Account = (New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier $users[1 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray`

Comment: Thanks, I got what I needed working thanks to your help.  Much appreciated.